# Need to grep value from in hash in perl

Tags: perl

I need to grep a particular value from each line shown below:

```
ABC_ROOT|/home/pulkit/pulkit_test/ABC/ABC-012/ABC04.16.103/lnx86
DEF_ROOT|/home/pulkit/pulkit_test/DEF/DEF192/DEF19.20.100/lnx86
GHI_ROOT|/home/pulkit/pulkit_test/GHI/GHI19.10.199/lnx86/tools.lnx86
JKL_ROOT|/home/pulkit/pulkit_test/JKL/JKL19.00.000/lnx86
```

From the above lines, I want to extract the values that has version numbers (`ABC04.16.103`, `DEF19.20.100`, `GHI19.10.199`, `JKL19.00.000`) and store these values in a hash using Perl. To store these values in an array, I used the below code with the help from this site:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open (File, "/home/pulkit/pulkit_test/abc_test.txt");
my @value;

map { m|/([^/]+)/lnx\d+| and push @value, $1 } <File>;

print join( "\n" , @value,"\n");
```

As I am very new to perl, can someone please help on how can I store these values in a hash.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear on what should be used as a key of hash elements. Your code snippet of _map_ is lacking source of data..

Comment: A hash is an associative array, meaning each element has a *key* and a *value*.  Is `ABC04.16.103` supposed to be used as the key or value of the element, and what should be used as the other?

Comment: Tip: `my @value; map { m|/([^/]+)/lnx\d+| and push @value, $1 } <File>;` is a pretty horrible way of writing `my @value = map { m|/([^/]+)/lnx\d+| } <File>;`

Comment: Tip: You shouldn't use two-arg open. Use `my $qfn = "..."; open(my $fh, '<', qfn) or die("Can't open \"$qfn\": $!\n");` Also note how I avoided using a global variable for the file handle, and how I added error checking.  (`open` is very prone to failing, and it's good to include the file name in the error message.)

Comment: Tip: `m{...}` is better than `m|...|` since `|` is commonly used in regex patterns.

Comment: Tip: In an array contains multiple "values", then `@values` is a better name than `@value`. (Use `@value` if the array represents the different parts of a single value.)

Comment: `print join( "\n" , @values, "\n");` outputs two line feeds at the end. It probably should be `print join( "\n" , @values ), "\n";` or `print "$_\n" for @values;`

Comment: Your question is not clear on what should be used as a key of hash elements. Your code snippet of map is lacking source of data.. – Polar Bear  >> the keys should be "ABC_ROOT, DEF_ROOT, GHI_ROOT, JKL_ROOT" and the values should be "ABC04.16.103, DEF19.20.100, GHI19.10.199, JKL19.00.000"

Comment: as hash, <code>my %value = map { my @m = m!/([^/]+)/lnx!; $m[0] => 1 } <File>;</code>

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

open( FILE, '<', 'sample.txt');

my %R = map { m{^([^\|]*)\|(?:/[^/]*)*/([^/]*)/lnx\d}; $1 => $2 } <FILE>;

print Dumper(\%R);
```

- `Dumper` is just for convenience and easy output
- `map` can return hashes `$1 => $2` does that
- the regular expression `m{^([^\|]*)\|(?:/[^/]*)*/([^/]*)/lnx\d}`
- `^([^\|]*)\|` - this captures the 'key' - the string at the beginning that ends in `|`
- `(?:/[^/]*)*` - this skips all the directories before the value - `(?:)` - is a non-capturing group

I think that regular expression is a bit to much, I would suggest using different approach:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

open( FILE, '<', 'sample.txt');

my %R = ();

while (<FILE>) {
    my @fields = split m{[|/]};
    my $value;
    do {
        $value = pop @fields;
    } until $value !~ /lnx\d+/;
    $R{$fields[0]} = $value;
}

print Dumper(\%R);
```

- instead of a regular expression, you split the line in multiple fields
- the $field[0] will be your key
- the value will be the last field before a field matching /lnx\d/

  - `pop @fields` gets the last element of the array